# why not display all items in StackPanel of xaml in new line?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

i want show all items as long text in StackPanel in windows phone 8.
but this code show all item only in one row and other items not go to next rows.
this is my code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="300">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Id: "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Foreground="GreenYellow" />
                                    <TextBlock Text=" , Adress:( " /><TextBlock Text="{Binding a3}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text=" , "/><TextBlock  Text="{Binding a2}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text=" , "/><TextBlock  Text="{Binding code}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text=" , "/><TextBlock  Text="{Binding a1"/>
                                </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how a `StackPanel` is supposed to work. The behavior you want is achieved by a `WrapPanel`, which doesn't exist natively in Windows Phone 8. You can get it in the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/); note that it works only for apps that target Windows Phone Silverlight (8.0), not WinRT (WP 8.1).

Comment: wow, greats. really special big thank you  Thomas Levesque. its really work good. very thank you.

Comment: its show developer of Microsoft not work good. so we need used external components and tools.

Comment: @RashedDIP, the WP toolkit is developed by MS ;)